# How to Generate KML file with Style using Geotools?

Tags: java, styles, kml, geoserver, geotools

I performed a lot of search around this question, and do not find any answer.

In a Java Program, I have a "SimpleFeatureCollection"(geotools) and a "StyleLayerDescriptor"(geotools) which contain my "SimpleFeatureCollection" style, and I need to generate a KML file using this style.

I actually generate successfully a KML file (without any style) using my "SimpleFeatureCollection" object with the following code:

```
static public boolean collectionToKMLFile(File iKMLFile, SimpleFeatureCollection iPolygonsCollection, StyledLayerDescriptor iStyle) throws IOException
{
    Encoder lEncoder = new Encoder(new KMLConfiguration());
    FileOutputStream lFileOutputStream = new FileOutputStream(iKMLFile);
    lEncoder.setIndenting(true);
    lEncoder.encode(iPolygonsCollection, KML.kml, lFileOutputStream);
    lFileOutputStream.close();
    return false;
}
```

I do not find any information on how to add style, I do not think it is impossible, do yo have an idea ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally decided to write a program to generate my own *Styled KML File*.

In fact, it is not really hard:

1. Write KML Header
2. Loop over your geometries and Write them
3. Write Kml Footer

All information relative to *KML* elements defined in KML Version 2.2 could be found here :

- [**"KML Reference"**](https://developers.google.com/kml/documentation/kmlreference)

Enjoy.

Comment: Can you share some code snippet please? I'm trying to do the same :(